# serialport read data empty dataspace from output on pycharm console

Tags: python

I'm trying to write(`write.py`) and read(`listener.py`) on same port .
I'm able to get data while running `listener.py`, but which is an empty space.
I tried to send byte string from write.py and on listener I'm getting like this

LISTENER OUTPUT:

b''

b''

b''

b''

and here's my code for `write.py`:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
print(ser.name)
ser.write(b"heloo")
```

and here's my `listener.py` code:

```
import serial
serCode=serial.Serial('COM4',9600,timeout=1)
while True :
    serRead=serCode.readline()
    # data=serRead.decode('ASCII')
    if 1>=1:
        print(serRead) #for this print I'm getting (  b'') output
        #print(data)   #for this print I'm getting (      ) output
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on same port"?  Are these two scripts running on the same computer (in which case I'd expect a "port already open" error), or on different computers (in which case how are they connected)?

Comment: both scripts are running on same computer and using same serial communication port

Comment: That makes no sense at all - the whole point of a serial connection is to talk to whatever device is at the other end of a serial cable.  Trying to run two programs on the same computer that talk to the same serial port cannot possibly work.